# Getting a page source after POST variables have been sent

Tags: c#, http, post, web

I have some code that logs me into Facebook and it works fine as far as returning me the page you see right after you log in.
But I'm trying to request my actual profile after I log in rather than just my news feed.
So I'd have to send my email and password to the login page, then request my profile.
How can I keep the login data around while requesting my profile?

Here is what I've got

```
    public static string logIn()
    {
        //get the cookies before you try to log in
        CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com"); 
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        cookies = response.Cookies;
        response.Close();

        //logging in
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1");
        getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        //sending the email/password
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("email=myemail@yahoo.com&pass=mypassword");
        getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
        newStream.Close();

        //returns the source of the page after logging in
        HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string source = sr.ReadToEnd();
        cookies.Add(getResponse.Cookies);

        //tries to get my profile source
        //everything works fine until here
        getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.facebook.com/myprofile");
        getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream());
        source = sr.ReadToEnd();
        getResponse.Close();
        return source;
    }
```

I've tried several ways of doing this and I have gotten it to return my profile, but it returns it as if I was not logged in and you can't actually view my profile (because it is set to private) 
So I need my login info to be included somehow when requesting my profile.

Comment: There are specific Facebook APIs to do this the proper way. You should not attempt to do this through the web interface. Take a look at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk.github.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start a CookieCollection at the beginning and use it for all requests.
A CookieCollection updates itself with new cookies whenever you do a request so using cookies.Add() was also messing it up.
But I got it working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This had me stumped for a while when I was making something similar. You need to make sure you're setting the proper cookies for your request after you've logged in. Try adding the new cookies to the `CookieCollection` object before applying them to your last request.

```
// ^ previous code ^
HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream());
string source = sr.ReadToEnd();

Uri facebookPage = new Uri("http://www.facebook.com"); // .GetCookies() only accepts a Uri
cookies.Add(request.CookieContainer.GetCookies(facebookPage));

getResponse.Close(); // Always make sure you close your responses

// V requesting your profile code V
```

Comment: I tried it this way with no luck.
I have another way I'm also trying that adds the cookies you get from logging in when doing the last request but also having no luck.
I updated the first post with this.

Comment: Sorry for the long response. Have you tried using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/, "Fiddler")? It's a web debugging tool that would be very useful in this situation. It can show the header information your program is sending/receiving, most importantly the cookies. I've found the best bet is to login/browse with your web browser with fiddler running and see what your browser is sending, then trying to replicate that with your program. I've changed one thing in my response as well, so you could try that.

Comment: I messed around some with fiddler and it looks like it's way over my head. I don't know much about this kind of stuff.
But I'm pretty sure my only problem here is with cookies. I still can't seem to find a way of sending the right cookies after trying tons of different ways.